# Deploy WIndows 7 over network

Tags: windows-7, networking

I want to deploy Windows 7 over the network with pre-installed software to 140 computers. I've read up on it, but I am not sure the exact process. Isn't there a fairly easy way to do this?

Comment: Same image to 140 workstations? Presume all identical hardware config? Licensing?
Looks like [PeteNetLive can show you how to use WDS](http://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0000180.htm) to accomplish that.

Comment: Same image, yes. They are identical hardware, we have a VLK.